# invalid literal for int() with base 10 0:00 in python code

Tags: python

I need to get only the year from a date column which is in this format "02/12/1908" from excel dataset, but am getting this a error "invalid literal for int() with base 10 0:00"

I have modify the code this way but not working still

```
dataFrame['Year'] = dataFrame['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[-4:]))
```

To

```
dataFrame['Year'] = dataFrame['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(float(x)[-4:]))
```

**Code**:

```
import numpy as npy    
import pandas as pdas     
from matplotlib import pyplot as pt    
import matplotlib    
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression    
import re
from pandasql import sqldf

dataFrame=pdas.read_excel('Project_Airplane_Crashes_and_Fatalities_Since1908.xlsx', sheet="Sheet")
matplotlib.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (12.0, 8.0)

dataFrame['Year'] = dataFrame['Date'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[-4:]))
perYear = dataFrame[['Year','Fatalities']].groupby('Year').agg(['sum','count'])

perYearFig,(xaxis,yaxis)=pt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(15,10))
perYear['Fatalities','sum'].plot(kind='bar',title='Fatalities by Year',grid=True,ax=xaxis,rot=90)
perYear['Fatalities','count'].plot(kind='bar',title='Accidents by Year',grid=True,ax=yaxis,rot=90)
pt.tight_layout()
pt.show()
```

A graph to be ploted

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code and instructions or data necessary to reproduce the problem. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The exception suggests that some of your dates include a time. `0:00` is not going to be parsable as a year, no matter what you do. Perhaps you should parse to a `datetime`, then extract the year from it afterwards?

Comment: The code `int(float(x)[-4:])` isn't going to work regardless of what's in `x`.  If `x` doesn't contain a valid string representation of a floating point value, then you'll get a similar exception to what you were getting before.  If you give it a valid float string in `x`, then it's going to throw an exception because you're trying to slice a float value like its a sequence type, which it isn't.

Comment: I would suggest replacing the lambda with a regular function, and then print the value `str(x)[-4:]` in that function to see what you're getting.  You might also want to print the full `x` value.  You need to see what your incoming data really looks like.  Alternatively, you could stop in your debugger and take a look.  Also, I'm guessing that you don't need the `str()` cast around `x`, as it's likely already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.to_datetime` and then get the year.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({"Date": ["02/12/1908"]})
dataFrame['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(dataFrame['Date']).dt.year
print(dataFrame)
```

**Output:**

```
         Date  Year
0  02/12/1908  1908
```